# Why won't box-sizing: border-box; work when applied to the container in 960.gs?

Tags: html, css, web, grid

I'm using box-sizing: border-box to everything on my page. However, when I add padding to the container element in my 960.gs grid, it bumps the second grid to the next line. It does, however work as expected if I add it to individual grid classes.

```
<header role="banner" id="header">
     <div class="container container_12">
          <div class="grid_4">
               logo here
          </div>
          <div class="grid_8">
               tagline here
          </div>
     </div> </header>
```

Adding 10px of padding to .conatiner wraps grid_8 to the next line. Adding 10px to both grid_4 and grid_8 doesn't (box-sizing works). Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it is working correctly.

`box-sizing: border-box` overrides the default behaviour where adding padding and borders to an (non-absolutely sized) element increases that element's total size. With `border-box`, all elements behave as if they've been absolutely sized with respect to padding: adding padding increases the internal space between the element's borders and its contents, but does not increase the total size of the element.

So what's happening is that by adding `padding: 10px` to `.container`, you decrease the amount of horizontal internal space available for `.container`'s contents. And since `.container`'s width does not grow (as specified by the `box-sizing` rule), and the child elements do not shrink, the second child must wrap, since the combined width of both child elements is now greater than the available internal space of `.container`.

Adding padding to the `.grid_` elements "works" (your definition of "works" assumed to be that `.container`'s children fit in one row and do not wrap) because according to the `box-sizing` rule, those elements should not gain width in addition to their set width (set by 960 gs) when they are given padding. The result of the added padding is instead to increase the space between the `.grid_` elements' borders and their contents ("logo here" / "tagline here"), and to decrease the `.grid_` elements' "internal width".

Basically, `box-sizing: border-box` means that padding (and borders!) gets added internally, rather than externally, and your example demonstrates this behaviour consistently.

[Here is more info on `box-sizing` values, plus some demos](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/box.html).

Comment: Yes, basically. I should note that `border-box`, as its name implies, is for sizing elements with respect to their borders, not just padding; that would be `padding-box` instead (a Mozilla extension that I'm not sure has been dumped). Although in this case, the difference doesn't really matter as 960.gs doesn't use borders, and padding is accounted for in both types of box sizing anyway. It's in `content-box`, the original W3C box model, that it isn't.

Comment: oh duh, just like the name says eh?  I've replaced a couple instances of "padding" with "padding and borders" to make it more correct.

Comment: Thank you for the thoughtful response. This helped me a ton (and it makes perfect sense).